# Conditional Mod-rewrite Variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

From my research (reading docs and trial and error) so far what I want to accomplish isn't possible. Currently we copy a big conditional over multiple times for everytime we want to redirect a user on a mobile device to our mobile site. This seems very inefficient to me though..

So for example we had

```
# Check if this looks like a mobile device
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(css|js|files) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !.*(nonmobile=1|testmobile=0) [NC]
# Redirect to base page on the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com [R,L]
```

which was easy, just send all non css/js/files requests to m.example.com (the mobile version of our site). Then we decided if it was a request for our `content`  directory we wanted it to go to a particular place so we copied that whole rule and put it above with a different re-write rule. So our .htaccess currently is

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp|driod" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(css|js|files) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !.*(nonmobile=1|testmobile=0) [NC]
# Redirect to sub page on mobile site
RewriteRule  ^/?(content)/(\d+)(.*)$ http://m.example.com/sub/$2 [NE,R=301,NC,L]


# if mobile and non specific send it to root
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(css|js|files) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !.*(nonmobile=1|testmobile=0) [NC]
# Redirect to base page on the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com [R,L]
```

Is there a way to test a condition or make a variable that can be tested?

So

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]
if(page ~= '/^\/?(content)/(\d+)(.*)$/') {
      RewriteRule  ^/?(content)/(\d+)(.*)$ http://m.example.com/sub/$2 [NE,R=301,NC,L]
} else {
      RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com [R,L]
}
```

I figure this can be done in PHP, but keeping it at the apache level would be most efficient I think... but maybe not, because it can't handle this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't chain the long list of rewrite conditions to multiple rules. Conditions will only ever apply to the immediately following rule. But depending on what the rest of your htaccess file looks like, you could negate the conditions and make it pass-through so nothing gets rewritten, *then* you can add your mobile rules. The idea is, if it's not mobile, don't do anything and stop rewritting, then everything after that must only apply to mobile:

```
# pass-through the 2 non-mobile conditions
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !"maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} macintosh [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# everything after this will be mobile
RewriteRule  ^/?(content)/(\d+)(.*)$ http://m.example.com/sub/$2 [NE,R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, with this approach we'd be rewriting every request though right? Current breakdown would read 1. Not mobile device, just send to root. 2. macintosh browser send to root as well. 3. `content` is the directory and it is one of our selected user agents send it to mobile's targeted directory. 4. it is one of our user agents but not the directory we care about so just send it to mobile's root.